# Is it possible to deploy django 2.2 on Google App Engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I just began to learn Django recently. I am trying to deploy a django project on Google App Engine. But I stuck when following tutorial on google: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

when I type: 
`python manage.py makemigration`

I got: following error:
`mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.`

After short research, apparently, I can't install mysqlclient 1.3.13 on Django 2.2 yet?? Is this a mistake? Am I missing something? Can I use mysqlclient 1.3.13 on django 2.2 ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to `pip install "mysqlclient>=1.3.13"`? How is it being installed?

Comment: Hey, i followed the tutorial step-by-step and it worked fine for me, did you change your Django version to 2.2 and that's when the issues started?

Answer (score 0):

Django support for Postgresql is much better than for mysql. I recommend you switching to postgres.

EDIT: 
I think that switching to postgres will solve this problem out of the box.

Comment: While I'm a PostgreSQL user, suggesting someone switches their entire backend database is a fairly drastic solution without knowing the details of the situation. Learning an entire new RDBMS is no trivial task, and if the user works in a MySQL shop, it is likely a non-starter.